# Invoking/Creating Delegate

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates

Good Day Everyone,

there are 2 ways I've noticed I can invoke/create delegate either

`MrDel MyDelegate = new MrDel(Mathmetics.Method);`

or

`MrDel MyDelegate = Mathmetics.Method;`

So my question is whats the difference between those 2 ways? Why Would I need to use first one if second one is much shorter to type and they seemingly doing the same thing? By going through some of the tutorials I'm seeing ppl either using first way or second way but they don't realy explaining WHY. Could you help me make it clear or point out where I can read about it, thank you.

FULL CODE:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void MrDel(int arg, ThingsToDo e);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MrDel MyDelegate = new MrDel(Mathmetics.Method);
        //MrDel MyDelegate = Mathmetics.Method;


        Method(MyDelegate);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same - the second is [Syntactic Sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_Sugar) for the first.  To confirm I looked at the IL generated for both, and they are identical:

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldftn       UserQuery.Method
IL_0008:  newobj      UserQuery+MrDel..ctor
IL_000D:  stloc.0     // MyDelegate

Method:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ret         

MrDel.Invoke:

MrDel.BeginInvoke:

MrDel.EndInvoke:

MrDel..ctor:
```

Comment: thank you! And its good you have pointed out to  IL - should have used it to look under the hood at first place! :D

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.  The syntax sugar was created to avoid having to write this:

```
   button1.Click -= new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

Which greatly bedevils new C# programmers.  As in: "What??  I have to create a **new** delegate object to **remove** it???".  Yes, you do.

Nobody complains about:

```
   button1.Click -= button1_Click;
```